# ¿Cómo obtener la URL completa en PHP?

Tags: php, url

Utilizo este código para obtener la URL completa:

```
$enlace_actual = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

El problema es que en `.htaccess` uso máscaras y redireccionamientos, por lo que la URL que se ve no coincide siempre con la ruta al fichero.

Lo que necesito es obtener la URL, lo que está escrito en la URL, nada más y nada menos. Es decir, **quiero el valor de la barra de direcciones del navegador y no la ruta del fichero en el servidor**. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: [Referencia cruzada en StackOverflow en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6768793)

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6768793

Answer (score 8, accepted):

para eso tienes que usar $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

```
$enlace_actual = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

La relación entre REQUEST_URI y PHP_SELF es más o menos como sigue:

- El webserver recibe del browser una solicitud en la forma de una url. Ésta se compone del host más el REQUEST_URI.
- El webserver intenta discernir si le están pidiendo un estático, un directorio, una regla de rewrite, o un script php
- Si es una regla de rewrite, el REQUEST_URI se asocia a un entrypoint en PHP que lo usará como parámetro.
- Si es un script PHP, se invoca y ejecuta ese script PHP.

Tanto si hay una regla de redirección de por medio como si no, el ciclo de vida del request termina ejecutando un script PHP, que es el PHP_SELF.

El PHP_SELF en muchos casos usa el REQUEST_URI para deducir los parámetros que se le han pedido asi que, aunque para el webserver el request ya no es su problema, dentro del script PHP sí se siguen procesando los parámetros de la URL original para generar la respuesta. Esto es válido para casi cualquier ejemplo de nice-urls, desde Wordpress hasta Laravel.

Comment: Nótese que esto es una traducción de la respuesta a la pregunta en SO [Get the full URL in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6768831/1983854)

Comment: En realidad ni siquiera miré SO para responder esto. Sólo C&P la pregunta y reemplacé una llave por la correcta. Saludos.

Comment: Interesante, gracias amenadiel. ¿Cuál es el motivo de usar `REQUEST_URI`? Leyendo en http://php.net/reserved.variables.server parecen similares

Comment: REQUEST_URI es la ruta que se ingresa en el browser. El webserver recibe el pedido y a partir de esa ruta intenta deducir si te refieres a un archivo estático, una directorio, una regla de redirección o derechamente un 404. Si es una regla de redirección, traduce el REQUEST_URI a un script PHP que es el que aparece en PHP_SELF al cual le pasa el mismo REQUEST_URI como parámetro.  El ciclo de vida del request cambia un poco si usar Apache con mod_php, apache con fastcgi, o nginx con php-fpm, pero esencialmente es como puse.

Comment: ¡Fantástica explicación, muchas gracias! Lo mismo puedes incorporarla a la respuesta en sí para que se vea más.

Comment: Ok, voy a complementar la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

Es una variable global que te lo da todo lo referente a la conexión url.

Visita : http://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 2):

> Adaptado de *[Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8891890/5290909)*.

Esta función devuelve la URL completa, incluyendo al protocolo y el host en casos donde `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` no esté configurado o cuando se está detrás de un proxy.

#### URL completa

```php
function url_completa($forwarded_host = false) {
    $ssl   = !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on';
    $proto = strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']);
    $proto = substr($proto, 0, strpos($proto, '/')) . ($ssl ? 's' : '' );
    if ($forwarded_host && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'])) {
        $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
    } else {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
            $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        } else {
            $port = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
            $port = ((!$ssl && $port=='80') || ($ssl && $port=='443' )) ? '' : ':' . $port;
            $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $port;
        }
    }
    $request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    return $proto . '://' . $host . $request;
}
```

#### Uso

```php
<div id="url"><?php
    $url = url_completa();
    echo htmlspecialchars($url);
?></div>
```

#### Valor devuelto

```
protocolo://̵u̶s̶u̶a̶r̶i̶o̶:̶c̶l̶a̶v̶e̶@dominio:puerto/ruta?cadena=de+busqueda̶#̶e̶t̶i̶q̶u̶e̶t̶a
```

- No se incluyen las partes tachadas (usuario, clave y etiqueta).
- No se muestra el puerto por defecto (80, o 443 en HTTPS).

#### Variables gestionadas por el cliente (navegador)

- `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Los caracteres que no están permitidos son escapados por el navegador antes de enviarlos.
- `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` no siempre está disponible.
  * Más información en *[HTTP_HOST vs. SERVER_NAME](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2297421/5290909)*.
- `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']` es asignado por proxies y balanceadores de carga.

#### Variables gestionadas por el servidor

- `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`. El servidor devuelve `empty` o `"on"` de acuerdo a si se está usando SSL (HTTPS).
- `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']`. Sólo acepta números de puertos válidos.
- `$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']`. Sólo acepta ciertos protocolos.
- `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`. Asignado manualmente en la configuración del servidor (no está disponible en [algunos casos](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44614) cuando la directiva [`UseCanonicalName`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname) no está habilitada).

---

### Etiquetas

Cuando se utiliza una etiqueta (`http://url.com/pagina#etiqueta`), la misma [no es enviada al servidor](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-4). En cambio, es gestionada por el cliente (navegador). Si se desea obtener el valor para agregarlo a la URL obtenida en PHP, se podría evaluar desde JavaScript con [`location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Location#Properties).

```js
var url = document.getElementById('url'); //el div del código anterior
url.innerText += location.hash;
```