# Compartir facebook Include PHP

Tags: php, facebook

Tengo un dos botones para compartir contenido de una página web (uno de fb y uno de tw).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy utilizando inlcude para repetir el contenido en todas las páginas `<?php include 'share.php';?>`. El problema es que facebook me pide una url específica para cada página, ¿cómo puedo lograr esto si include solo me permite repetir contenido? Hay forma de detectar la url según la página en donde me encuentre?. Con Twitter no hay problema (lo detecta automáticamente).

```html
<span class="text-share">Comparte:</span>

<div class="bt">
            <a class="bt-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fkhapac.com/portafolio-pecsa-multimedia/">Facebook</a>
        </div>
        
<div class="bt">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="bt-twitter" data-hashtags="Khapac" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
            <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Si dejas la URL vacía (el parámetro `u`), entonces Facebook automáticamente tomará la URL de la página en la que esté el botón de compartir. 
Así por ejemplo, el siguiente código abrirá una ventana con la URL de la página que lo contiene:

```
<div class="bt">
  <a class="bt-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u">Facebook</a>
</div>
```

Si prefieres escribir una URL, entonces deberías mirar esta otra pregunta de SOes, en la que se explica lo que buscas: [¿Cómo obtener la URL completa en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49890/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-la-url-completa-en-php)